# how to insert multiple values to a single unique key in python

Tags: python

I have df and for the first column i want to capture the second column values as list and make a list with `key` being the unique id from first column and list of values from second column being `values`.

Here is the example df:

```
Bra100001       Bra100001
Bra100001       Bra011864
Bra100002       Bra011842
Bra100002       Bra100002
Bra100003       Bra100003
Bra100004       Bra100004
Bra100005       Bra100005
Bra100006       Bra100006
Bra100007       Bra011656
Bra100008       Bra100007
Bra100009       Bra100008
Bra100009       Bra011638
Bra100010       Bra103178
Bra100010       Bra011635
```

My required output is

```
Bra100001:(Bra100001,Bra011864),Bra100002:(Bra011842,Bra100002),Bra100003:Bra100003 and so on....
```

Here is my psuedo code

```
with open("test_blast.txt", 'r') as fh_in:
        prev = None
        result = {}
        for line in fh_in:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.split()
            if prev == line[0]:
                result[line[0]] = line[1]
            prev = line[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the output to be an **ordered dictionary of tuples**:

```
import collections

result = collections.OrderedDict()

with open("test_blast.txt", 'r') as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        col = line.split()
        if len(col)<2: continue
        if not col[0] in result:
            result[col[0]] = ()     
        result[col[0]] += (col[1],)
```

if you want the output to be a **string** in the **exact format** given in your example, you can further process the result this way:

```
out=[]
for r in result:
    s  = str(result[r]).replace(', ', ',').replace("'",'')
    if s.endswith(",)"): s = s[1:-2]
    out.append(r+':'+s)

print ",".join(out)
```

**You can see a demo here:** http://repl.it/46l/3

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('test_blast.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

records = [l.split() for l in lines]
records = [r for r in records if len(r) == 2]  # drop empty line at end in my tests

result = {}
for r in records:
    if not result.get(r[0]):
        result[r[0]] = []    # this is the first reference to key so initialize value
    result[r[0]].append(r[1])

# below is only needed for sorted output
keys = sorted(result.keys())
for k in keys:
    print k, ': ', result[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, just straight tuples or lists, `x = ('x1', 'x2')`, or use a hash with buckets:

```
foobar = {
    'key1': [(some_vals)];
    'key2': [(some_other_vals)]
    ...
    }
```

then just reference foobar